# How to get haskell code after desugaring arrow syntax?

Tags: haskell, ghc, arrows

I currently try to solve my problem [HXT: Can an input change with the arrow syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701238/hxt-can-an-input-change-with-the-arrow-syntax) and therefore and want to see the haskell code after the ghc compiler desugars the [Arrow syntax](http://www.haskell.org/arrows/syntax.html). How can I do this?

I already tried `-ddump-ds` but with this flag I get a horrible long code because also all types are resolved. Is there a way to see the code with just arrow syntax desugaring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original [arrow project](http://www.haskell.org/arrows/index.html) provided a parser, called `arrowp`, which is [available on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrowp) and translates the arrow syntax to Haskell98:

```
cabal install arrowp
arrowp --help
arrowp source.hs > desugared.hs
```

## Example

Source has been taken from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701238/hxt-can-an-input-change-with-the-arrow-syntax#22701238).

### source.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

data Person = Person { forname :: String, surname :: String } deriving (Show)

parseXml :: IOSArrow XmlTree Person
parseXml = proc x -> do
    forname <- x >- this /> this /> hasName "fn" /> getText
    surname <- x >- this /> this /> hasName "sn" /> getText
    returnA -< Person forname surname

main :: IO ()
main = do
    person <- runX (readString [withValidate no]
                               "<p><fn>John</fn><sn>Smith</sn></p>"
                    >>> parseXml)
    putStrLn $ show person
    return ()
```

### `arrowp source.hs`

```
{-# LINE 2 "source.hs" #-}
module Main (main) where
{-# LINE 2 "source.hs" #-}
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

{-# LINE 4 "source.hs" #-}
data Person = Person{forname :: String, surname :: String}
            deriving Show

{-# LINE 6 "source.hs" #-}
parseXml :: IOSArrow XmlTree Person
{-# LINE 7 "source.hs" #-}
parseXml
  = (arr (\ x -> (x, x)) >>>
       (first (this /> this /> hasName "fn" /> getText) >>>
          arr (\ (forname, x) -> (x, forname)))
         >>>
         (first (this /> this /> hasName "sn" /> getText) >>>
            arr (\ (surname, forname) -> Person forname surname)))

{-# LINE 12 "source.hs" #-}
main :: IO ()
{-# LINE 13 "source.hs" #-}
main
  = do person <- runX
                   (readString [withValidate no] "<p><fn>John</fn><sn>Smith</sn></p>"
                      >>> parseXml)
       putStrLn $ show person
       return ()
```

Comment: Thanks! I try it. Is it the same code used in current ghc?

Comment: @tampis: According to http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrowp, arrowp is "a preprocessor that reads Haskell with arrow notation and outputs Haskell 98. Note that GHC 6.2 or later has built-in support for arrow notation, so if you're only using GHC, you don't need this preprocessor". However, even if they differ, they will do only so in names or style, since the [desugaring rules are fixed](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/arrow-notation.html) and [the same](http://www.haskell.org/arrows/syntax.html), as far as I can see. But I haven't used arrows yet, sorry :/.